# How to make UWP Tooltip display on grid hover

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, tooltip

In my UWP app, I have a Grid element that contains a Tooltip and a ContentControl. When I hover my mouse over the grid, I'd like to see the tooltip. However, currently the tooltip only displays if I hover over the image inside the grid. Is there a way to achieve this without messing with the "mouse enter" events of the grid boundaries?

```
<Grid Height="65" Margin="5" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Left" Content="You just hovered here"/>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to give the Grid control a light color as the background, then the Tooltip will show when the mouse hovers over the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Background` property of the `Grid` to `Transparent`:

```
<Grid Height="65" Margin="5" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Background="Transparent">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Left" Content="You just hovered here"/>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

This should make the `Grid` capture the mouse events and display the tooltip.